# Insert Facebook email address in database with Omniauth-facebook and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I've created a sign up/in feature on my app using device and omniauth. Users can sign up through a sign up form and then sign in. They can also sign in through Facebook.

But when I sign up with my own email adres john@whosjohn.com and then sign in with my Facebook account which also uses john@whosjohn.com I've created 2 different users.

I've check with User.all what's going on and when I log in throughFacebook I'm not saving an email adres. The value is nill.

Can someone explain how I can save the users email adres that's linked to his Facebook account into my user table?

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def password_required?
    false
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you inspect `auth` inside `from_omniauth` to make sure that you are getting users email? Simply put `raise auth.inspect` and let me know the output.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed where do I put `raise auth.inspect` ? I've put it in `where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      raise auth.inspect
    end` which doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't give any output in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Create a Authorization model**

```
rails g model Authorization
```

**In migration add following code**

```
class CreateAuthorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :authorizations do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :token
      t.string :secret
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**then**

```
rake db:migrate
```

**In your models/authorization.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**In your models/user.rb**

```
has_many :authorizations

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  authorization = Authorization.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid.to_s).first_or_initialize
  authorization.token = auth.credentials.token
  if authorization.user.blank?
    user = User.where('email = ?', auth["info"]["email"]).first
    if user.blank?
     user = User.new
     user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,10]
     user.email = auth.info.email
     user.save
    end
   authorization.user_id = user.id       
  end
  authorization.save
  authorization.user
end
```

Hope this will help you.